# What difference it make when I make a constructor of enum private or default?

Tags: java, enums

I have a enum class as below:

```
public enum TargetingName {

CONTENT("Content", "Content Targeting"), TECHNOLOGY("Technology", "Technology Targeting");

private TargetingName(String textToSelect, String textDisplayed) {
        this.textToSelect = textToSelect;
        this.textDisplayed = textDisplayed;
    }

    private String textToSelect;
    private String textDisplayed;

    public String getTextDisplayed() {
        return textDisplayed;
    }

    public String getTextToSelect() {
        return textToSelect;
    }
}
```

If I don't write private in constructor of enum does it make it default? If yes, what would be the difference? If No, then how to make a default constructor?

Comment: constructors of enums HAVE TO BE private, otherwise, your enum could become 'less' of an enum. an enum is a fixed list of values, if it's not private, some other class might add values without control from the enum class itself.

Comment: Thanks @Stultuske. I what is I dont write any access modifier before constructor? Would it be default? If yes, what would be the behaviour? I can add values by calling it from class within the package right?

Comment: "In an enum declaration, a constructor declaration with no access modifiers is private." "It is a compile-time error if a constructor declaration in an enum declaration is public or protected"

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks. That means a enum constructor with out a access modifier is not default but private. how can we define it with default? I guess defining it with default would b 'less' an num as described by Stultuske.

Comment: @Darshit you cannot make it 'default'. Enums are a special thing in java and the JLS specifies them to have private constructors only. And that makes sense because you are not supposed to create new instances/constants from the outside.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **[8.9.2. Enum Body Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2)**
>
> In an enum declaration, a constructor declaration with no access modifiers is private.

It wouldn't make any difference except you would need to write an extra word.

I saw developers putting `private` to make it more explicit (to emphasise the fact you can't use an enum constructor outside the enum). I find it unnecessary.

> If I don't write `private` in constructor of enum does it make it default?

If by "default" you mean `private`, yes.

If by "default" you mean *package-private*, no. Neither `public` nor `protected` is allowed. Enum constructors are always `private`.

> **[8.9.2. Enum Body Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2)**
>
> It is a compile-time error if a constructor declaration in an enum declaration is public or protected (§6.6).

Answer (score 5):

An enum constructor cannot be anything other than private.

> In an enum declaration, a constructor declaration with no access modifiers is private.
>
> ...
>
> It is a compile-time error if a constructor declaration in an enum declaration is public or protected.

There is no reason for it to be anything other than private: you can't manually create new instances of the enum (that's kinda the point of an enum).

If you want something you can create instances of, use a regular class.

Comment: just to complement, missing JLS 8.9: "An enum type has no instances other than those defined by its enum constants. **It is a compile-time error to attempt to explicitly instantiate an enum type**"